# Посчитать количество прошедших дней от определенной даты

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Есть дата формата 11.05.2020
Как посчитать количество прошедших суток с этой даты на текущий момент? Пока что в голову приходят только костыли типа: получить текущую дату в этом же формате, через split разбить на день/месяц/год, сравнить и посчитать, но я уверен что это не в дзене Python и есть метод проще.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
old = datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=11).date()
print(now-old)
```